# Java EE cdi inject different implementation for test

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, java-ee-6, cdi

I have got service for `solr` and in that service i am inject `solr http` server implementation. But for test i need inject another server implementation - Embedded `solr`. 
How i can do this simply using `cdi` ? Any suggestion ...

In my solution i need to use cdi qualifier:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER })
public @interface SolrServer {

    Type value();

    enum Type {
        HTTP, EMBEDDED;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create an `@Alternative` in your test source and add that to an alternatives declaration in the beans.xml you use to test.